# How to use SAS hash object ?

Tags: sas

I tried to define a key in SAS hash object . But got error . Here is the code :

```
data sasuser.contrib ; 
input empid $ qtrnum $ amount ;          
datalines;
e2 qtr1 11 
e3 qtr2 12 
e4 qtr3 13 
e5 qtr4 14 
e6 qtr1 15 
;
run; 

data difference (drop = goalamount);
length goalamount 8; 
if _N_ = 1 then do;                           
declare hash goal(); 
goal.definekey ("QtrNum") ; 
goal.definekey ("GoalAmount") ; 
goal.definedone() ;                         
call missing(qtrnum, goalamount) ;       
goal.add(key : 'qtr1' , data : 10 ) ;        
goal.add(key : 'qtr2' , data : 15 ) ;     
goal.add(key : 'qtr3' , data : 5  ) ; 
goal.add(key : 'qtr4' , data : 15 ) ;   
end;  
set sasuser.contrib ;  
goal.find() ;  
diff = amount - goalamount;   
run  ;
```

The error is `ERROR: Variable qtrnum has been defined as both character and numeric`

I tried removing the set statement, but still could not debug it . How can I improve my code ?

Answer (score 2):

Your call missing statement is initialising `qtrnum` as numeric while the set statement is trying to read it in as character. You can set it to numeric by adding a `qtrnum $8.` to your length statement.

You will then find you have an additional error as SAS expects two keys on the hash table. I think what you intended to have was `goal.definedata ("GoalAmount");`. This will tell SAS to load the data values you specified into `GoalAmmount`, rather than to try to match it as a key variable.